# xlrd retrieves wrong date when excel cell value is =TODAY()

Tags: python, xlrd

If the value in a cell is `=TODAY()`, xlrd wrongly retrieves the date of document's last save.

Does anyone know where I can find the relevant code within `xlrd` sources so to edit? Any suggestions for a workaround will also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`xlrd` does not parse and evaluate formulas.  `xlrd` gives the last evaluated value of any formula because that is what is saved in the document.

If you need the function to be evaluated at the time you read the document, you will need to use another tool.

If you are on Windows and have Excel installed, you can access Excel via a COM object:

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\path\\wb.xls") # backslash required by excel 2007 and later
print xl.Cells(1,1).Value # cell "A1" of the active sheet
```

Comment: 2nd `Dispatch()` is redundant and fails with `NameError`. Missing: code to open the required workbook.